# Two marbles are selected from a sack containing two red marbles, two blue marbles, and one black marble. The color of each marble is recorded.

Tags: probability

Find the sample space S for the experiment. (Enter your answers as a comma-separated list. Use R for red, B for blue, K for black.)

Since there is only 1 black marble, the sample space should have 8 outcomes. I came up with

S={KR, KB, RR, RB, RK, BB, BR, BK}

but it's incorrect. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Can you guys lead me to the right path?

Comment: I don't think the order of picking matters. So $RB$ should be the same as $BR$ etc. although you should clarify that this is the case.

Answer (score 2):

The order in which we pick them seems not to matter, so we have $\{BB, RR, BR, BK, RK\}$ as all the options, in that case (two the same colour) or two different colours, where one of the latter could be black. These have different probabilities, clearly. Rohan's second idea does have equiprobable outcomes. I don't know which kind of sample space you want fom your question.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the sample space for the balls in the bag: {$R_1, R_2, B_1, B_2, K$} where $i$ represents the $i$-th ball of a particular colour. Now, consider the sample space for the total number of ways of picking two of them: {$R_1R_2, R_1B_1, R_1B_2, R_1K, R_2B_1, R_2B_2, R_2K, B_1B_2, B_1K, B_2K$} $...(1)$ **provided the order of picking is not important**.

**If that is not the case**, also add {$R_2R_1, B_1R_1, B_2R_1, KR_1, B_1R_2, B_2R_2, KR_2, B_2B_1, KB_1, KB_2$} as additional sample spaces to $(1)$. Hope it helps you.